# Align type declarations vertically in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, format, webstorm

How do you force WebStorm to align type declaration values vertically when running "Reformat Code"?

I have this:

[image]

And I want this when I run "Reformat Code".:

[image]

I have tried enabling `Align on value` in the "Wrapping and Braces" settings for TypeScript, but running "Reformat Code" brings the values back towards the colon.

[image]

^^ doesn't work when reformatting code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently possible, please follow [WEB-43078](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43078) and linked tickets for updates